# DropDownListFor <TModel,TProperty> method to take another parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, generics, expression

In here i bind Dropdown list using Enum.(bind is successful).But i wanted to add css class to it,But in here it need to add,
"DropDownListFor "<"TModel,TProperty">" method to take another parameter for css class name." 
My Dropdownlist

```
 @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.ReportType)
```

But i need belowone to accept in MyDropdownlist method,

```
 @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.ReportType, new {@class="form-control"})
```

Helper Class(Dropdownlist Method )

```
        public static MvcHtmlString DropDownListFor<TModel, TProperty>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper,
        Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression) 
        where TModel : class
    {
        TProperty value = htmlHelper.ViewData.Model == null 
            ? default(TProperty) 
            : expression.Compile()(htmlHelper.ViewData.Model);
        string selected = value == null ? String.Empty : value.ToString();
        return htmlHelper.DropDownListFor(expression, createSelectList(expression.ReturnType, selected));
    }
```

I get thisone from [This Link](http://www.spicelogic.com/Journal/ASP-NET-MVC-DropDownListFor-Html-Helper-Enum-5).In the comment section in that article someone ask for the exactly same question..

Comment: you can add the css class in html attributes parameter in dropdownlistfor helper @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CountryCode, Model.Countries, Resources.Placeholder_Country, new { @class = "select-mandatory choosen", id = "ddlCountry", placeholder = Resources.Placeholder_Country })

Comment: @FrebinFrancis But it need to accept in that "public static MvcHtmlString DropDownListFor" method

Comment: you just want to get the Enum types as a list right ? You can create a list of Enum values without this helper.

Comment: @FrebinFrancis Yes.I get that list,I only need to know about the css accepted rule to that generic method

Comment: for that you need to write the code for creating a select element like this http://20fingers2brains.blogspot.com/2013/04/custom-dropdownlist-html-helper-in-mvc3.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to add the parameter as `object htmlAttributes` and create your dropdown list using  `htmlHelper.AnonymousObjectToHtmlAttributes(htmlAttributes)`.

Your full helper code would become:

```
public static MvcHtmlString DropDownListFor<TModel, TProperty>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper,
    Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression, object htmlAttributes ) 
    where TModel : class
    {
    TProperty value = htmlHelper.ViewData.Model == null 
        ? default(TProperty) 
        : expression.Compile()(htmlHelper.ViewData.Model);
    string selected = value == null ? String.Empty : value.ToString();
    return htmlHelper.DropDownListFor(expression, createSelectList(expression.ReturnType, selected), null, htmlHelper.AnonymousObjectToHtmlAttributes(htmlAttributes));
}
```

I find in situations like yours often the best solution is to take a look at what the actual source code is doing for the `SelectExtensions`.

**[Html.DropDownListFor source code reference](https://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/System.Web.Mvc/Html/SelectExtensions.cs)**